# Using Spree on one app for several different clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a rails app that serves several businesses. Now we want to add spree (shopping cart) for each one of those companies. Is there a way to do it? If not, perhaps you can give solution suggestions.

Thanks,

John

Comment: you mean marketplace app right? for multiple vendor application you just need to create one separate role from spree dashboard and override spree ability.rb (cancancan authorigation) and give them access so they can view and manage there stuff

Comment: You may also want to use the [multi-domain](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-multi-domain) extension.